# na.omits removes all rows with NA in any column and not only on the specified columns

Tags: r

Considering the following object (data):

```
   collection.number weight bill.length bill.height bill.width
1         XXXXX29985   11.5       16.10        4.07       6.74
2         XXXXX29986   11.6       17.43        4.17       6.39
3         XXXX391828     NA       14.85        4.02       7.19
4         XXXX328017     NA       16.92        3.38         NA
5            XX28024     NA       14.79          NA       6.00
6            XX28095     NA       15.80        4.17       6.54
```

I'm trying to remove all rows that have NA in any of the following columns: bill.length, bill.height and bill.width.

when I do:

```
data.filtered<-na.omit(data[3:5])
```

or

```
data.filtered<-na.omit(data, cols = c("bill.length","bill.height","bill.width"))
```

it removes all row that have NA in the "weight" column and not only in the specified columns. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to remove those rows?

Comment: you can use `is.na` or `complete.cases` ie `data[complete.cases(data[3:5]),]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, an easier option is `?complete.cases` which by desription takes arguments

> a sequence of vectors, matrices and data frames.

and returns a logical vector, which can be used as row index for subsetting the dataset

```
data[complete.cases(data[3:5]),]
#  collection.number weight bill.length bill.height bill.width
#1        XXXXX29985   11.5       16.10        4.07       6.74
#2        XXXXX29986   11.6       17.43        4.17       6.39
#3        XXXX391828     NA       14.85        4.02       7.19
#6           XX28095     NA       15.80        4.17       6.54
```

---

`na.omit` returns the dataset itself by removing rows with any NA on one of its columns.  So, when we apply `na.omit` on the subset data, it returns only the subset of rows of the the data already subset by columns